# How do I add a class to an automatically wrapped parent

Tags: jquery, css

The CMS I use wraps all images with `<p>` tags and I need to be able to retroactively add a class to the `<p>` in order to apply specific styling. How would I target the following code using jQuery to do this:

```
<p><img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="photo details" /></p>
```

For other cases where I have needed to add a class I done the following:

```
$('.main > p > img').addClass('img-responsive');
```

However in my current situation I need to target the paragraph that has an image inside it.

My desired outcome is:

```
<p class="has-img"><img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="photo details" /></p>
```

Comment: `$('.main > p > img').parent().addClass('img-responsive');`

Comment: $('p:has(img)').addClass('has-img');

Comment: $('.main p img').closest("p").toggleClass('img-responsive',true)

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not sure that title change makes sense

Comment: @freedomn-m I am not sure that your edit added clarity to my question.

Comment: @lurker thanks for the prompt response. Very helpful. I replaced 'img-responsive' with 'has-img' and it worked great.

Comment: @j08691 maybe not, but the answer to a simple, generic "how do I add a class" is simply `.addClass()` *which doesn't help OP* and anyone else in the future **actually looking for how to add a class** won't be particularly helped by the generic question title or any answer that may be given.  You're welcome to change it, but I felt it was too simple for the question being asked (and it shouldn't include "using jquery" from the sample in [ask]).